# Incorporating certain conditions with in the existing condition in xsl

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

Let me start first this below question i am asking may be reptetive one but I am stuck up in one thing. I have tried my best and need advise from you guys, please advise.

As  below you can see the template I have defined in **XSLT 1.0** and there are certain conditions also as shown below:

```
<xsl:template name="direction_emm_cashflowGDS">
    <xsl:param name="TradeHeaderVar" />
    <xsl:param name="ReturnSwapTradeVar" />
    <xsl:param name="ReturnLegVar" />
    <xsl:param name="InterestLegVar" />
    <xsl:param name="legReferenceVar" />
    <xsl:variable name="cdfPartyRef">
        <xsl:value-of select="$TradeHeaderVar/bookingEntityPerspective" />
    </xsl:variable>

<xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when
            test="($legReferenceVar=$ReturnLegVar/@legIdentifier and 
                   $cdfPartyRef=$ReturnLegVar/payerPartyReference) 
                  or 
                  ($legReferenceVar=$InterestLegVar/@legIdentifier and 
                   $cdfPartyRef=$InterestLegVar/payerPartyReference)">
            <xsl:value-of select="'Pay'" />
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="'Receive'" />
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose> 
</xsl:template>
```

Now as I have organized certain conditions in `xsl:when` depending upon the specified requirement and now there is a slight change in the requirement.

That is let say:

if `$legReferenceVar=$ReturnLegVar/@legIdentifier` is not equal then in that case a select of error is need to be displayed.

In other words, if `$legReferenceVar != $ReturnLegVar/@legIdentifier` then error message to be diasplayed as

```
<xsl:value-of select="'EEROR'" />
```

Similiar is the case with another change in requirement is that if `$legReferenceVar=$InterestLegVar/@legIdentifier` is not equal then a select of error needs to be dispalyed. `$legReferenceVar != $InterestLegVar/@legIdentifier` then error message to be diasplayed as

```
 <xsl:value-of select="'EEROR'" />
```

Please advise how to incorporate these changes in the existing conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[xsl:choose](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt.html#section-Conditional-Processing-with-xsl%3achoose) can have multiple [xsl:when](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt.html#element-when) elements:

> It consists of a sequence of [xsl:when](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt.html#element-when) elements followed by an optional
>   [xsl:otherwise](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt.html#element-otherwise) element. Each [xsl:when](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt.html#element-when) element has a single attribute,
>   test, which specifies an expression. The content of the xsl:when and
>   [xsl:otherwise](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt.html#element-otherwise) elements is a template. When an [xsl:choose](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt.html#section-Conditional-Processing-with-xsl%3achoose) element is
>   processed, each of the [xsl:when](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt.html#element-when) elements is tested in turn, by
>   evaluating the expression and converting the resulting object to a
>   boolean as if by a call to the boolean function. The content of the
>   first, and only the first, xsl:when element whose test is true is
>   instantiated. If no xsl:when is true, the content of the xsl:otherwise
>   element is instantiated. If no [xsl:when](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt.html#element-when) element is true, and no
>   [xsl:otherwise](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt.html#element-when) element is present, nothing is created.

Simply add your new **ERROR** condition as another [xsl:when](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt.html#element-when) criteria:

```
<xsl:template name="direction_emm_cashflowGDS">
    <xsl:param name="TradeHeaderVar" />
    <xsl:param name="ReturnSwapTradeVar" />
    <xsl:param name="ReturnLegVar" />
    <xsl:param name="InterestLegVar" />
    <xsl:param name="legReferenceVar" />
    <xsl:variable name="cdfPartyRef">
        <xsl:value-of select="$TradeHeaderVar/bookingEntityPerspective" />
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$legReferenceVar != $ReturnLegVar/@legIdentifier
                        or $legReferenceVar != $InterestLegVar/@legIdentifier">
            <xsl:value-of select="'ERROR'"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when
            test="($legReferenceVar=$ReturnLegVar/@legIdentifier 
                   and $cdfPartyRef=$ReturnLegVar/payerPartyReference) 
                 or 
                  ($legReferenceVar=$InterestLegVar/@legIdentifier 
                   and $cdfPartyRef=$InterestLegVar/payerPartyReference)">
            <xsl:value-of select="'Pay'" />
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="'Receive'" />
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose> 
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: thanks a lot but it print error for every one, that should not be the flow..!

Answer (score 1):

Just add a `<xsl:when>` clause with your new condition, as a new child of `<xsl:choose>`:

```
<xsl:choose>
   <xsl:when test="$legReferenceVar != $ReturnLegVar/@legIdentifier">
      <xsl:text>ERROR</xsl:text>
   </xsl:when>
   ...etc.
```

Comment: If I misunderstood what you were asking, please let me know.